# Simple issue...Need a new line

Tags: apex

from the first VF page

```
string address = address1 + ',' +address2 + ',' +address3;
```

in the second vf page I'm calling this values as

```
address = apexpages.currentpage().getparameters().get('address');
```

Hwncw my values in the URL looks like  `example-developer-edition.ap1.force.com/site?address=test1,test2,test3..`.But in my vfpage need to display them as

```
 address   test1
           test2
           test3
```

IF I use \n in between the address (say  `string address = address1 + '\n' +address2`) It is taking only the test1 value in the url....Hope this clear..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See what this one does for you:

```
String multiLineaddress = apexpages.currentpage().getparameters().get('address').replaceAll(',', '\r\n');
```

You can also experiment with `<br/>` instead of `\n` (probably the outputText you have in there will need `escape="false"` because it will encode this tag).

Or wrapping your output in `<pre>...</pre>` block.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to create a list in your VF Page extension that gets filled by Splitting the parameter you just passed (take a look at [String.Split](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_string.htm)) then in your page you will need to use [`<apex:repeat>`](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_repeat.htm) on the list you just created where you can simply use a `<br />` in each repeat so that your addresses get displayed on a different line